# How to register .sty and .mf  to  the LaTeX system?

Tags: installing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files)

I am using the default LaTeX command provided by ygwin on Windows. Just wonder when I have new `.sty` and `.mf`'s residing in a different directory than my source `.tex` files, how to use them? I could in principle put all of them together and it works. But rather, I would keep a repository of these files separated from my `.tex` source files.

Comment: Please read this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files

Comment: @xport: thank you. Is there any way for latex to do something like `#include <dir_to_sty/mysty.xty>` in C programming? I would want to have the sty files in arbitrary folder.

Comment: You must register your own packages or document class to the LaTeX system. I  think you cannot make a reference to them as you can do in C.

Comment: On Unix/Linux systems, you can override the `TEXINPUTS` path variable, like `TEXINPUTS=/path/to/dir: pdflatex project.tex` or `TEXINPUTS=/path/to/dir: xelatex project.tex`, so it's easy to override that in a Makefile for example. I don't know if there's something of the kind on Windows.

Comment: @Raphink: did what you said. But now it says some .mf's are not found. It seems these mf's are not controlled by TEXINPUTS environment variable, correct? How to specify these .mf's then? Thank you.

Comment: Also this one, registering to TeX Live http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20160/2099