# How to register my own packages or classes in a separate drive to TeX Live installation?

Tags: installing, texlive

I create my own documentclasses and packages in some directory of `tex\latex`. The directory `tex\latex` itself might be in any other directory in any drive. I can register the packages/classes to Miktex as already posted in [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-tex-files/20121#20121). Putting the documentclass or packages in a dedicated directory in a separate drive is practically useful to avoid data loss when the system crashes.

But how to do this for TeX Live?

---

Based on Ulrike's answer I do the following steps and it works.

### Step 1

Open `C:\texlive\2010\texmf\web2c\texmf.cnf` to see how `TEXMFLOCAL` is defined.

```
% .... other settings before this line have been removed for simplicity. 
%
% A place for local additions to a "standard" texmf tree.
% This tree is not used for local configuration maintained by
% texconfig, it uses TEXMFCONFIG below.
TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local
%
% .... other settings after this line have been removed for simplicity.
```

### Step 2

Open  `C:\texlive\2010\texmf.cnf` and modify it as follows.

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
OSFONTDIR = $SystemRoot/fonts//
%============== Below this row is my modification ====================
%
% My custom packages and classes are
% in E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary/tex/latex/misc.
%
TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local,E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary
%
%
% It is wrong if you do like below
% TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local,E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary/tex/latex/misc
% or
%TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local,E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary% comments
```

Packages and classes must be in some subdirectory of `tex\latex`. In my example above, they are in `E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary/tex/latex/misc` directory. I am not sure spaces in the path still work in OS other than Windows.

### Step 3

Invoke `texhash` as follows.

[image]

### Step 4

Done. Congratulation.

Old comments below this question should be removed because they might be no longer relevant to this final edit.

Comment: @xport I wouldn't use spaces in the path, they are a sure source of problems. Try asking `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` and see what's the answer.

Comment: @xport: spaces in paths are extremely dangerous and may be the reason for failure. Append `;` at the end. This ensures that a possible system-wide setting of `TEXMFLOCAL` is evaluated too.

Comment: @xport. Your settings seem to be ignored. Please verify, whether the `texmf.cnf` you modified is actually used: Run the command `kpsewhich texmf.cnf`. It should return `C:/texlive/2010/texmf.cnf`

Comment: @xport: What does `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` say?

Comment: @xport. It is important that `texhash` and `kpsewhich` read the correct configuration file, that is the one you modified, otherwise your modifications were made in vain.

Comment: @xport. Strange. Even a non existing directory put into `TEXMFLOCAL` should at least be shown by `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL`. I am running out of ideas :(

Comment: @xport: I tried both, Linux and Windows. Added (fake or existing) directories show up in `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` output. `texhash` registers files added to existing directories.

Comment: @xport: As a workaround for your Windows box (since your `texmf.cnf` doesn't seem to be read) I suggest setting the environmental variable `TEXINPUTS` by `set TEXINPUTS=.//;E:/A/MyLaTeX/MyLibrary//;` in a `*.bat` file which also does the TeXing of your document.

Comment: I don't have a full TeXLive but I have a skeleton (for luatex). I have added various texmf trees (e.g. from miktex) for various drive to texmf.cnf and it works fine. The syntax I used:

Comment: Continuation (I hit enter before the end): `TEXMFLOCAL = I:/TeX-Roots/microtype,I:/TeX-Roots/UFlocaltexmf,...` (commas between the roots, no slashes at the end). The variable TEXMFLOCAL is then used later on in the texmf.cnf like this: `TEXMF = {!!$TEXMFMAIN,!!$TEXMFLOCAL, ...}`. kpathsea reads *all* texmf.cnf. Settings in earlier ones wins. Check the list of pathes with `kpsewhich -show-path=cnf`. If you have a miktex installed: Check that you are not using its `texhash` (try `texhash --version`).

Comment: @xport `...` means etc (more texmf trees and/or variables). Additional information: I don't have a comma at the end of such a setting. There is somewhere a kpathsea.pdf which contains details about the syntax etc.

Comment: @xport: really? I wouldn't be so confident. You probably have another `texmf.cnf` hanging around.

Comment: @xport Would you please report in your question the output of `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMF`? The creation of the `ls-R` files depends on another variable (`TEXMFDBS`); I fear that many important parts are missing from your `TEXMF`.

Comment: @egreg: kpathsea uses *all* texmf.cnf it finds. So it should be ok if the local texmf.cnf's is empty at the start and it should be enough to add only the value you want to change to it. (In context MKIV there is also a texmfcnf.lua involved, but I don't know if there too all versions are used. When I asked even the context experts didn't seem to be certain how the configurations files are processed.)

Comment: @Ulrike: I know this; the problem I see is exactly setting `TEXMF` to that value in the "almost empty" one. Can you write down an answer showing exactly the contents of your "almost empty" file?

Comment: @egreg Ah I see what you mean. Yes I also have some doubts if it is necessary and advisable to (re)set TEXMF in the local texmf.cnf. I have only one "home made" texmf.cnf for my luatex skeleton and so naturally it also contains all the settings which are normally in the global texmf.cnf.

Comment: I think appending `,E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary` to `TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local` in the global texmf.cnf is the easiest way. But don't forget to execute `texhash` as well.

Comment: @AlexG, @xport: I tried to add a directory to ``TEXMFLOCAL = ...`` in ``c:/texlive/2013/texmf.cnf`` and made the following observations: 1.) it doesn't seem to matter if you use a comma or a semicolon to separate the directories, 2.) the line must end with a line break/newline (didn't test if LF or CR or both are necessary), otherwise the value is not used.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK. At request I sum up my comments as an answer:

I don't have a full TeX Live but I have a skeleton (for LuaTeX). I have added various `texmf` trees (e.g. from MiKTeX) from various drives to `texmf.cnf` and it works fine. The syntax I used is

```
 TEXMFLOCAL = I:/TeX-Roots/microtype,I:/TeX-Roots/UFlocaltexmf,...
```

(commas between the roots, no slashes at the end, no comma at the end, the ... stand for more pathes).

The variable `TEXMFLOCAL` is then used later on in my (complete) `texmf.cnf` like this:

```
TEXMF = {!!$TEXMFMAIN,!!$TEXMFLOCAL, ...}
```

Normally `TEXMF` should already have this definition in the global `texmf.cnf` so it shouldn't be necessary to reset it in the local `texmf.cnf`. kpathsea reads *all* `texmf.cnf`. Settings in earlier (local) ones wins.

You should check if you didn't loose the texmf trees from the original `TEXMFLOCAL` definition (perhaps it did contains something before).

Check the list of `pathes/texmf.cnf` with `kpsewhich -show-path=cnf` or (according mpg) `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf`.

If you have a MiKTeX installation, check that you are not using its texhash (try `texhash --version`).

Answer (score 11):

With a default TeXLive installation you have a directory `c:\texlive\texmf-local`. There you can save your own files. This local directory has the same subdirectories as the default main one. LaTeX files should be saved in `texmf-local\tex\latex\...`. After saving your files run as command `texhash` to update the data base.

you can run from the command line `kpsewhich -expand-var '$TEXMFHOME'`, then you see the default home directory. You can change this variable for your needs. You have three trees: `$TEXMF`, `$TEXMFLOCAL`, and `$TEXMFHOME`.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily add package directories which reside outside the `c:/texlive` directory. Just append them, separated by `;`, to the `TEXMFLOCAL` variable in the configuration file `c:/texlive/texmf.cnf` of your installation and run the `texhash` command. This will add all files found to the file name data base.

**EDIT:**
Here is my texmf.cnf:

```
% (Public domain.)
% This texmf.cnf file should contain only your personal changes from the
% original texmf.cnf (for example, as chosen in the installer).
%
% That is, if you need to make changes to texmf.cnf, put your custom
% settings in this file, which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf.cnf, rather than
% the distributed file (which is .../texlive/YYYY/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf).
% And include *only* your changed values, not a copy of the whole thing!
%
TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/texmf-local;/home/grahn/texpkgs
TEXMFHOME = $TEXMFLOCAL
TEXMFVAR = $TEXMFSYSVAR
TEXMFCONFIG = $TEXMFSYSCONFIG
ASYMPTOTE_HOME = $TEXMFCONFIG/asymptote
TEXINPUTS=.//;
main_memory = 30000000
```

As far as I know, this file was installed during TeXLive installation (I was using the `--portable` option). The additions I did are the `TEXINPUTS` and `main_memory` lines and the additional directory in `TEXMFLOCAL` for illustration. Always use `/` in paths (even for Windows). `TEXINPUTS=.//;` lets TeX search for files in subdirectories of the current one.

Comment: @xport: the usual value for `TEXMFLOCAL` is given by `TEXMFLOCAL = $TEXMFROOT/../texmf-local` Copy this line into the `texmf.cnf` file and append `;x:/path/to/right/place`. Note that this requires your external disk is always mounted with the same specifier (here `x`). Maybe Windows has some way to refer to devices by name.

Comment: @xport: I think so, but I don't know Windows. I would use the exact capitalization, though, just in case.

Comment: @xport: always use `/` in paths.

Comment: @xport: you have many `texmf.cnf` files. Try `kpsewhich -a texmf.cnf` to list them. The first (and shorter) one is the one you found, meant for local editions. The other one is much longer, contains all the settings and should not be edited manually but can serve as example/documentation.

Answer (score 3):

[As already mentioned by @mpg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20160/how-to-register-my-own-packages-or-classes-in-a-separate-drive-to-tex-live-insta#comment38454_20165), there are 2 `texmf.cnf` files. The one with a shorter path is for user-defined settings. The other one with a longer path is for factory-default settings and should not be edited by users.

However, in my experience, the user-defined `texmf.cnf` seems to be ignored or its settings do not affect anything even though you invoke `texhash` after editing it. That is why I always edit the factory-default `texmf.cnf` file.

Open the factory-default `texmf.cnf`, locate `TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local`, and append `;E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary`. So it becomes

```
TEXMFLOCAL = $SELFAUTOPARENT/../texmf-local;E:/A/My LaTeX/MyLibrary
```

Finally invoke `texhash`.

Note that you have to change `\` to `/` and use `;` as appending delimiter. When you update your TeXLive installation then redo this ritual because factory-default `texmf.cnf` will be reset to its default settings.

Answer (score 2):

With TeX Live 2017 it is very easy to register a new TEXMF tree. Assume your files are in `E:/A/MyLaTeX/MyLibrary/tex/latex/misc`. So the new TEXMF tree would be `E:/A/MyLaTeX/MyLibrary`. Now, open a console window and type in:

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees add "E:/A/MyLaTeX/MyLibrary"
```

Linux or OS/X users may need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo tlmgr conf auxtrees add "E:/A/MyLaTeX/MyLibrary"
```

You can test for all these auxiliary trees and their search order using

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees show
```

And if you want to remove such an auxiliary tree just use

```
tlmgr conf auxtrees remove "E:/A/MyLaTeX/MyLibrary"
```

(here it may also be necessary to use `sudo` as shown above).