# Getting Gregorio to work on Windows 7

Tags: installing, texlive, windows, gregorio

I need help trying to get [Gregorio](http://home.gna.org/gregorio/) working on Windows 7 x64.  I've installed TeX Live 2012 and Gregorio, and have configured TeXworks.  When I try to compile a tex file, it tells me that it can't find `gregoriotex.sty`, and I also get errors saying it can't find `gregoriotex.cls`.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `gregoriotex.sty' not found.
```

The last few lines of texworx's console output were:

```
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luacode/luacode.sty))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty))
```

I got this error following the directions [here on the Gregorio site](http://home.gna.org/gregorio/introduction-texworks) I have followed.

It seems like there is another setting somewhere in TeX Live, but I can't find it.

Here are some [commandline directions](http://home.gna.org/gregorio/introduction-commandline), whereupon I get the same error.

How can I get this to work?

---

*Follow-up question: [Texlive and Gregorio Manual Font Installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103517/texlive-and-gregorio-manual-font-installation)*

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please post a complete MWE (minimum working example) that shows what you've done so far and generates the errors and/or warnings you're trying to fix.

Comment: @mico Thanks for answering.  I've added a link.

Comment: For a moment there, I thought the OP was talking about [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)...

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure he was talking about Gregorio.

Comment: @BGM It's a "site joke"; I'm in no way connected to the Gregorio project.

Comment: @egreg Oh!  Okay, no worries.  I only said that because jubobs spoke about me in the third person as if I weren't there.  However, it is pretty funny now that I know egreg is you!

Comment: @Jubobs Nope. The OP wasn't talking at all; at least, not in this forum.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen - Indeed: he was chanting. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I learned the solution to the missing `sty` file error by [reviewing this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20160/how-to-register-my-own-packages-or-classes-in-a-separate-drive-to-tex-live-insta).  Now, I installed Gregorio at `c:\texlive\gregorio`.

I don't know why the Gregorio installer can't handle it, but I copied the folder at `c:\texlive\gregorio\tex` from its application folder to `C:\texlive\texmf\tex\latex` - and I tried it also at `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex` - either of those seem to work to fix the problem of the missing `sty` file.

Then, make sure that your have the fonts installed correctly - [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103517/texlive-and-gregorio-manual-font-installation/103535#103535); this is very important.

Also, if you are trying to use [NotatioAntiqua](http://notatioantiqua.sourceforge.net/index.html) with Gregorio (it is a GUI that eliminates the user's having to interact with the commandline), there is a trick there, too.  So, assuming that you have installed notatioantiqua to `c:\texlive\notatioantiqua\`

Copy the file
`gregorian.cls`
from
`C:\texlive\notatioantiqua\share\contrib\class\`
to
`C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\gregorio\`

And then, in the commandline, run
`texhash`

Besides all that, in the .gabc files where the score is described, comment (or don´t use) the line related to text alignment with the notes:
`%centering-scheme: latin;`

**[UPDATE]**

Gregorio has been updated to version 2.3 as of June 2013, and just about all of these installation issues have been corrected.  Here is a link to the download repository:
http://download.gna.org/gregorio/releases/

Comment: Looking into the `install.py` in the `tar.gz` file I would call it a bug, that they hardcoded the path to the local-texmf as `/usr/local/texlive/2010basic/texmf-local`. Without knowing the installation routine for the `gregorio-setup.exe` I assume, it is hardcoded there, too. Submit a bug report to them with pointers to your related TeX.SX questions. One should upon installation get the opportunity to input the local-texmf path.