# Installation of own *.sty files in TeXstudio?

Tags: packages, texstudio, texmf, texlive-2019, styles

How do I have to include my own `*.sty` files in TeXstudio (with default setting, e.g. with PdfLaTeX)?

According to the log file TeXstudio uses TeX Live 2019 .

The `*.sty` files are organised in folders with separate subfolders e.g.

```
/beamer/base/themes/color/  
/beamer/base/themes/font/  
/beamer/base/themes/theme/  (the main *sty file ist located here, it include than e.g. corresponding color)  
/briefe/ ……  and so on
```

`kpsewhich –show-path ls-R` shows the following path:

```
/usr/local/share/texmf
/usr/share/texmf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist
/var/lib/texmf
```

I have already tried to copy the *`.sty` folder into the first three paths as root and afterwards I executed `sudo texhash`.

Additionally I have created the subfolder `/home/ich/texmf/tex/latex` and tried to copy the `sty`-folder there, too, and executed `texhash`.

`whereis texlive` shows `/usr/share/texlive`.

`kpsewhich texmf.cnf` shows `/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf`. A comment inside it explains that `/etc/texmf/texmf.d` should be modified or own `*.cnf` should be used and then `update-texmf` should be invoked.

`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME` shows `~/texmf`.

`kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` shows `/usr/local/share/texmf`.

I am using TeXstudio V 2.12.16 (Flatpak) on Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te) Note that TeXStudio is just the editor.

Comment: The other question is very similar (I have found it bevor), but it do not solve my problem. Maybe I misunderstand something.  
kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME
shows ~/texmf

I tried again the answer from Stefan Kottwitz:   create new subdirectory    ~/texmf/tex/latex/   and placed my sty-folder there.  
kpsewhich filename.sty shows nothing

Comment: I don't know exactly how TexLive deals with own .sty files, but on MikTeX yo must refresh the File Name Data Base as shown in this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20121/140133).
About installing on TexLive, check [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20160/how-to-register-my-own-packages-or-classes-in-a-separate-drive-to-tex-live-insta).

Comment: The answere in the other question does not  solve my problem

Comment: If I look in the file ~/texmf/ls-R than I can see my complete sty folder, but I got still the error from TeXstudio that the sty inlcuded with \usetheme is not found